# JS Slick Slider: variable width images

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I want to implement a slider for images of fixed height but variable width. For this I would like to use the [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

In the examples it shows a demo for items of variable width, but there the item width is specified inline for each element. When trying to do this with my images, the slider loads only the first two items to loop and then shows a big empty area. There are also strange glitches when navigating manually.

My markup structure [edited to reflect changes]:

```
.logo-slider
  a.slider-next
  .slider-inner
    a // repeats for each element
      img
  a.slider-prev
```

My JS/CoffeeScript code: [also with updated selectors]

```
$('.logo-slider').each (_idx, elem) ->
  slickElem = $(elem).find('> .slider-inner')
  slickElem.slick(
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    variableWidth: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    arrows: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    slide: 'a'
  )
  $(elem).find('> .slider-next').on 'click', () ->
    slickElem.slick('slickNext')
    return
  $(elem).find('> .slider-prev').on 'click', () ->
    slickElem.slick('slickPrev')
    return
  return
```

If you happen to know a library that does this, feel free to suggest it: I'm not set on Slick but would like to avoid rolling my own code for this.

EDIT:

I changed my markup so it doesn't use a `ul` and `li` anymore, only `a` tags. That allowed me to get rid of a lot of CSS and now everything seems to work at first. But the carousel only loops the first two items and then waits until last item is the only visible one before suddenly putting the remaining items back into the container and looping them, too.

Comment: The thing is, the `variableWidth` should solve your problem. Since you didn't provide your full code, it is *impossible* to investigate what is wrong. Please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Had to set `slidesToShow` from the default (1) to a high-enough number (7 in this case) so that at least that number of items would be wrapped.